# Seperate spring.factories into multiple files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In Spring Boot, you can do the following:

`src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories`

```
# Auto Configure
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.AConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.BConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.CConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.DConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.EConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.FConfiguration,\
```

Which is very nice. However after a year of development the list of auto configuration is now **> 15 lines**, which makes it hard to manage.

Would like to know if it is possible to separate the **spring.factories** into multiple files? Preferably would like to keep the whole project in one JAR.

Or maybe there is another ways to help organize the `EnableAutoConfiguration` that I am not aware of?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for this question.

*Note: This exact solution assume that you only used **`EnableAutoConfiguration`** in your `spring.factiores`, it would crash if you use more than one type of config inside `spring.factories`.*

One can do:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories
src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-2.factories
src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-3.factories
src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-4.factories
```

and merge this into one file.

Note, I am using **Maven Antrun** but I suspect Gradle would also have a similar feature.

In your `pom.xml`, add the following:

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-ci</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>

                                <replace token='org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=' value=',' 
                                        dir="${project.build.directory}/classes/META-INF">
                                    <include name="spring-*.factories"/>
                                </replace>
                                <concat destfile="${project.build.directory}/classes/META-INF/spring.factories" overwrite="yes" append="yes">
                                    <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes/META-INF" includes="spring-*.factories" />
                                </concat>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And in `spring.factories` is the normal config:

```
# Auto Configure
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.AConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.BConfiguration
```

But in spring-2.factories and others, you start with `,\` instead of the default statement:

`spring-2.factories`:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.CConfiguration
```

`spring-3.factories`:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.DConfiguration
```

---

After all that, the outcome `spring.factories` in your output class directories will be a very nice:

```
# Auto Configure
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.AConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.BConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.CConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.DConfiguration
```

Comment: That strikes me as brittle.  You now have a custom expectation on how those files are formatted, and need to update your pom if you add another.  Have you considered just using comments to separate your `spring.factories` file instead?

Comment: [Have you considered just using comments] The whole point of my question is to explore ways to make it so I can use multiple files for config. I can of course, keep using just comment to make things organize, but I don't want to for personal preference.

Comment: [You now have a custom expectation on how those files are formatted] This is a major flaw in this answer, so I welcome any additional answer to this question :) [and need to update your pom if you add another] This is fixed, now it watches the whole directory

Comment: See my edit, now there will be no custom expectation regarding the implementations, thanks for your comment to point out this issue!

Comment: Coming back to this answer 2 years later, this is a terrible method to implement Auto Configuration, would advice module instead of this any time of the day.

Answer (score 4):

While using spring-boot we use multiple "starters", each with an auto-configuration and `spring.factories` file.

So, one way could be to split your project into modules - one for each auto-configuration, define a dedicated `spring.factories` file in the module, and import all the modules as a runtime dependency in the main application module.

You can use maven or gradle to manage the multi-module project and the dependencies among them:

Gradle: https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/

Maven: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module

Example:

root

- moduleA

  - src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories
- moduleB

  - src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories

and so on...

Comment: This seems very promising! Before accepting the answer, let me go and check out if this is feasible in my project, thanks.

Comment: sure, let me know in case you have specific implementation issues with this.

Comment: I have study `modules` and it doesn't seems to suit my use case, I just want one project so doesn't make sense to use multi module. I have submitted a more suitable answer for my question. Anyway thanks for your time, much appreciated!